# Discontinuous multiplicity in UML Class diagram

Tags: uml, associations

I just have a quick question regarding multiplicities on unary associations in UML. So I want to specify that an instance of a class is linked to either non or two instances of the same class. Can I express this by putting the multiplicity as "0, 2" or is this not allowed?

Comment: You should confirm the answer of @Geert Bellekens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't. A multiplicity is expressed as a combination of a lower-bound and an upper-bound.

From the UML 2.5 specs

> The multiplicity bounds may be shown in the format:
>
> ```
> <lower-bound> ‘..’ <upper-bound>
> ```

If you want to express either 0 or 2 you'll have to use multiplicity `0..2` and add an extra contraint to express the fact that cardinality 1 is not allowed. This can be simply done by attaching a constraint like `{ cardinality must be 0 or 2 }`.

Comment: This constraint can also be expressed in UML itself by redefining the association end property.

Comment: @JimL. How? Can you post an answer?